# Setting request headers globally

Tags: javascript, electron, nightmare, request-headers

One way, to set the requester headers in nightmare library is to pass them as a second argument of `goto` method:

```
let headers = {
  'accept-language' : 'en-US'
}
nightmare.goto("https://stackoverflow.com/", headers);
```

Is there a way, to set them globally, or rather for each `nightmare` instance to not pass them explicitly on each navigation?

Comment: There's `.header` but I'm not sure if that's for subsequent requests. Either way, a simple wrapper should be sufficient, no?

Comment: @DaveNewton Yes. I think I will go with wrapper if there is no other way. Just wanted to make sure I'm not overlooking anything.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to achieve this.

Define your headers in an object.

```
let headers = {
  'accept-language' : 'en-US'
}
```

Set headers within a loop using [.header(header, value)](https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare#headerheader-value) method on your `nightmare` instance.